# JHipster gets out of memory on Heroku when using the free plan

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I have the latest pure JHipster 3.2 deployed to Heroku. I'm using the free-plan subscription at Heroku.

After deployment has been completed I get below error in the log:

- Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
- Process running mem=569M(111.1%)

Seems like the memory is exceeded. Do the JHipster work with free plan ? What options do I have to make use of my free plan running JHipster at Heroku or other PaaS ?

Comment: Which configuration?

Comment: Monolithic with postgresql and sass

Comment: I did not setup anything in the Heroku just deployed as instructed in the jhipster doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it normally works. There are even people using JHipster on Raspberri Pi, so 512Mo should be enough. But still remember you are on the free plan:

- You might want to remove the cache (the cache helps for performance, but uses memory)
- It also depends on the underlying box, and that depends what Heroku/AWS gives you, and that varies over time. Remember it's the free plan, so you have no guarantee